# How to change the after login,index page of wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change the default index page loaded after login in worpress ? I want to set a new page as index page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Peter's Login Redirect plugin to achieve this functionality. 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-login-redirect/

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Dashboard > Settings > Reading**, where you can set a static page to be displayed as front page.

You can use either specific page or post to be used as a static page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to edit your theme, here are some other options you can put directly inside the theme.

1) This will display the entire login form, which will redirect the user to `http://www.mysite.com/?page_id=2` after they login:

```
<?php
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
  $redirect_args = array('redirect' => 'http://www.mysite.com/?page_id=2');
  wp_login_form($redirect_args);
}
?>
```

2) This will display a *Login* link that will take the user to the normal login form, then redirect them to `http://www.mysite.com/?cat=1` after they login:

```
<?php
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
  $redirect_to = '/?cat=1';
  echo '<a href="' . wp_login_url($redirect_to) . '" title="Login">Login</a>';
}
?>
```